# center img vertically and horizontally inside div overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` `height:520px;` and `width:100%;` and I have a slideshow imgs inside it.

I wanted the `imgs` to be centered in full div. just like the `background-size:cover center center` but with `img`.

Here is my code (tried several things, didn't work perfectly):

```
<div class="container-fluid cont"  >
  <div class="cycle-slideshow">
      <img src="/img/1.jpg" >
      <img src="/img/2.jpg" >
      <img src="/img/3.jpg" ">
      <img src="/img/4.jpg" >
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont{
height:520px; 
width:100%; 
margin:0;
padding:0; 
margin: 0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
}

img{
min-width:100%; 
position:absolute; 
margin:auto; 
}
```

Comment: Make a fiddle with your code :)

Comment: What is the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/bhd3w1bv/

Comment: @Maddy The problem is that the image is not centered vertically when it's resized, as I said in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guide by Chris Coyer on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) is a great resource for such things.

If you don't know the images' height, you can do this:

```
.cycle-slideshow {
  position: relative;
}

.cycle-slideshow img {
  margin: 0 auto;               // – for centering them horizontally

  position: absolute;           // – relative should work as well, if the `img`s are
                                //   the only children of `.cycle-slideshow`

  top: 50%;                     // – for centering them vertically.
  transform: translateY(-50%);  // – don't forget vendor prefixes:
                                //   http://caniuse.com/#search=transform
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had `top:50%` but forgot `transform: translateY(-50%)` obviously.